# Openni launch process has died

Tags: openni, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running : `roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch`

I face the following problem:

> [ INFO] [1335797962.331964828]: [/openni_node1] Number devices connected: 1
> [ INFO] [1335797962.332508611]: [/openni_node1] 1. device on bus 001:25 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00363A22527050A'
> [ INFO] [1335797962.350725955]: [/openni_node1] searching for device with index = 1
> openni_node: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:412: boost::shared_ptr::reference boost::shared_ptr::operator*() const [with T = xn::NodeInfo, boost::shared_ptr::reference = xn::NodeInfo&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
> [openni_node1-2] process has died [pid 25516, exit code -6].
> log files: /home/vgaspar/.ros/log/11017564-92d5-11e1-bbff-001d60d75fe4/openni_node1-2*.log

system : ubuntu 11.10 , ROS: electric

installed openni with `sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect`

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32986/openni-launch-process-has-died/) by [vgaspar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2277/vgaspar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-04-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try: roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

---

Originally posted by [kshitij](https://answers.ros.org/users/1481/kshitij/) with karma: 115 on 2012-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same problem under fuerte/12.04. I also get the boost assert (also mentioned in http://answers.ros.org/question/11925/ros-kinect-roslaunch-openni_launch-opennilaunch/). Before this assert, I get one threading-related python exception per process:

`Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored`

The problem seems to be a conflict with the Linux driver. Removing it with

`sudo modprobe -r gspca_kinect`

and

`sudo modprobe -r gspca_main`

solves the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Stéphane Magnenat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1250/st%C3%A9phane-magnenat/) with karma: 83 on 2012-06-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stéphane Magnenat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1250/st%C3%A9phane-magnenat/) on 2012-06-12**:
After some more in-depth experiments, it seems that `openni_camera` is crashing often here on fuerte/12.04

**Comment by [Stéphane Magnenat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1250/st%C3%A9phane-magnenat/) on 2012-06-12**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/33622/openni_launch-not-working-in-fuerte-ubuntu-precise/ discusses the question in details...

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2013-05-24**:
thanks man, the remove method works for me! Fuerte on Ubuntu12.04 with openni-dev 1.5.2.23 and ps-engine 5.1.0.41